# Error : Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists

Tags: 7, emails

I have Drupal 7.43 installed on my hosting account, and I am using phpmailer to send all emails. It is giving the following error:

[image]

> Type phpmailer
>   Date Monday, March 21, 2016 - 15:39
>   User shyamzawar
>   Location http://bmcc-troika.net/?q=admin/config/system/phpmailer&render=overlay
>   Message SMTP error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>
> Subject: PHPMailer test e-mail
>
> Body:
>
> Your site is properly configured to send e-mails using the *PHPMailer*
>   library.
>
> Message:
>
> ```
>    array (  
>      'id' => 'phpmailer_test', 'module' => 'phpmailer',
>      'key' => 'test', 'to' => 'shyamzawar@ymail.com',  
>      'from' => 'shyam007zawar@gmail.com', 'language' => NULL, 'send' => true,  
>      'headers' => array(  
>        'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal',  
>      ),  
>    )
> ```
>
> Severity error

Comment: The output contains the error: "Could not connect to SMTP host."